# How to get the content of a textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This questions has been asked before, however, I'm unable to find an answer for my specific scenario.

I have a few checkboxes, in which if the box is checked, I want the 'Copy' to copy the content of the textareas next to the checked boxes.

```js
function copySelect() {
  var copyString="";
  $(".category>input").each(function (index, element) {
      if (element.checked) {
          copyString += element.nextSibling.innerText + " ";
      }
  });
  copyToClipboard(copyString);
}

function copyToClipboard(text) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(text).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkbox-group">
  <div class="category">
    <input type="checkbox" id="content1" value="state" />
      <textarea class="box" id="text1">Test content 1</textarea><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="content2" value="salePrice" />
      <textarea class="box" id="text2">Test content 2</textarea><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="content3" value="manager" />
      <textarea class="box" id="text3">Test content 3</textarea>
  </div>
  <input id="copybtn" type="button" value="Copy" onclick="copySelect()" />
</div>
```

I've tried changing `element.nextSibling.innerText` to `element.nextSibling.value` or `element.nextSibling.innerHTML`, but they all return undefined.

Comment: `element.nextSibling.value`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement

Comment: `$(".category>input:checked").map((i, e) => $(e).next().val()).get().join(" ")`

Comment: Always worth a quick review: [MDN nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) *Browsers insert Text nodes into a document to represent whitespace in the source markup. Therefore a node obtained, for example, using Node.firstChild or Node.previousSibling may refer to a whitespace text node rather than the actual element the author intended to get.* - your .nextSibling is **whitespace** - use .nextElementSibling: `e.nextElementSibling.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

element.nextSibling returns any kind of node, in this case it returns a text node, You should user element .nextElementSibling to get the next element (Input, textArea, select). Then you can get the text with value.

I corrected your code snippet.

```js
function copySelect() {
  var copyString="";
  $(".category>input").each(function (index, element) {
      if (element.checked) {
          copyString += element.nextElementSibling.value + " ";
      }
  });
  copyToClipboard(copyString);
}

function copyToClipboard(text) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(text).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkbox-group">
  <div class="category">
    <input type="checkbox" id="content1" value="state" />
      <textarea class="box" id="text1">Test content 1</textarea><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="content2" value="salePrice" />
      <textarea class="box" id="text2">Test content 2</textarea><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="content3" value="manager" />
      <textarea class="box" id="text3">Test content 3</textarea>
  </div>
  <input id="copybtn" type="button" value="Copy" onclick="copySelect()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).next().val()` when loop the input checkbox

```js
function copySelect() {
  var copyString="";
  $(".category>input").each(function (index, element) {
      if (element.checked) {
          copyString += $(this).next().val() + " ";
      }
  });
  copyToClipboard(copyString);
}
```